# Como verificar se uma variável está definida?

Tags: javascript, variáveis, undefined

Tentei fazer dessa maneira:

```
else if (vCodUG === undefined)
```

e deu erro de:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: vCodUG is not defined

[image: erro no console]

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Ao invés de comparar valores

```
vCogUG == undefined
```

utilize o operador [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof):

```
typeof vCogUG === "undefined"
```

[Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/brandizzi/nT5Nz/):

```
if (typeof vCogUG === "undefined") {
    alert("vCogUG é undefined");  // Será mostrado
} else {
    alert("O valor de vCogUG é " + vCogUG); // Não será mostrado
}

var vCogUG = 3;

if (typeof vCogUG === "undefined") {
    alert("vCogUG é undefined"); // Não será mostrado
} else {
    alert("O valor de vCogUG é " + vCogUG); // Será mostrado
}
```

Comment: Deve-se utilizar o operador `===`, pois é garantido que `typeof` sempre irá retornar uma string, tornando o código mais rápido.

Answer (score 15):

Use o operador [**`typeof`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof):

```
if (typeof nomeVar != 'undefined') {}
```

Comment: +1 por linkar pra documentação ;)

Comment: Deve-se utilizar o operador `!==`, pois é garantido que `typeof` sempre irá retornar uma string, tornando o código mais rápido.

Answer (score 14):

As respostas do LeoFilipe e do brandizzi estão corretas.

Existe no entanto uma alternativa que você pode utilizar para uma verificação similar:

```
var vCogUG;
vCogUG === undefined;
```

Se a variável vCogUG já existir e for acessível no escopo, **ela não será sobrescrita**. Caso contrário, terás uma variável com valor indefinido. Em ambos os casos, podes comparar da maneira como estava a fazer em seu código. Eu prefiro esta forma, pois assim comparamos o valor da variável com `undefined`, ao invés de comparar seu tipo com a string literal `"undefined"`.

**edição:** O Gibson chamou a atenção para o fato de que, dependendo do contexto, você vai sim sobrescrever a variável. Isso ocorre com closures (veja o comentário dele). Se estiver dentro de um closure ou de uma função auto-invocada, é melhor recorrer ao `typeof` mesmo.

Comment: Essa é uma excelente maneira! Para mim, toda comparação com `undefined` deveria ser assim. O único problema é que nem sempre a variável foi declarada. O que força a usar os outros métodos. Aparentemente há muitos programadores JavaScript que gostam de uma emoçãozinha: "a variável existe? Não existe? Cenas para o próximo capítulo!" :P

Comment: Se a variável não foi declarada, você a declara logo acima daonde for verificar se está indefinida - É isso que proponho aqui ;) Experimente no console: `var foo = 1; var foo; foo === undefined;`

Comment: O problema dessa técnica é se a variável for herdada de um contexto léxico mais amplo (ex.: um *closure*). [Exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/hsGjZ/). Nesse caso ela sobrescreve sim a variável do contexto externo, e você acaba com um resultado diferente do teste via `typeof` ([exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/hsGjZ/1/)).

Comment: @mgibsonbr eu não sabia disso. Valeu!