# Como verificar undefined de maneira correta no Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, undefined

Qual é a melhor maneira de verificar se um elemento/variável é `undefined` no Javascript?
Já vi alguns exemplos usando `variavel === undefined` e outros usando `typeof variavel == "undefined"`.

Comment: Relacionado (mas no meu entender, não é uma duplicata): http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/19273/como-verificar-se-uma-vari%C3%A1vel-est%C3%A1-definida?rq=1

Answer (score 18, accepted):

O mais correto é utilizar `typeof variavel === "undefined"`, pois `undefined` pode ser sobrescrito utilizando `window.undefined`, fazendo com que a comparação `variavel === undefined` retorne valores inesperados.

Na versão 5 do ECMAScript, não é possível mais sobrescrever `window.undefined`, embora por compatibilidade com engines mais antigas seja recomendado não utilizar este formato de comparação.

Observação: algumas pessoas utilizam `if ( variavel ) {` para checar se a variável esta definida. Isto não é confiável, pois `variavel` pode ter valores que são interpretados como `false`, e portanto não entrando no `if` mesmo que a variável esteja definida.

Se o que você deseja é verificar se `variavel` foi declarada, você deve utilizar o operador `in`. Isto acontece pois quando uma variável é declarada, mas não é inicializada explicitamente, implicitamente ela é inicializada com o valor `undefined`. Logo:

```
console.log(typeof x === "undefined"); // true
console.log("x" in window); // false
var x;
console.log(typeof x === "undefined"); // true
console.log(x in window); // true
```

Comment: Faltou aspas no `"x" in window`. E a propósito, esse teste só se aplica no *top-level*, certo? Ex.: `(function() { var x; console.log(x in window); })();` ainda vai retornar `false`.

Comment: Sem ler a especificação do JS eu não sei argumentar, mas, se você executar: `(function test() { var x; console.log("x" in window); })();` o resultado é `false`. Mas, se você executar `(function test() { var x; console.log(x in window); })();`, o restultado é `true`. Testei isso utilizando o console de desenvolvedor do Chrome. Talvez o comportamento seja um pouco diferente quando executado dentro de uma página de verdade. Sobre as aspas, no primeiro teste (`console.log(x in window); // false`), elas são realmente necessárias. No segunto, elas interferem no resultado.

Comment: Isso é porque ele está interpretando `x` como "a coisa que você quer saber se existe". Se você fizer `var x = "foo"; console.log(x in window);` ele vai retornar `false`, mas se você fizer `var x = "Number"; console.log(x in window);` ele vai retornar `true`. E se você fizer `var x = "undefined"; console.log(x in window);` ele vai retornar `true` (pois `window` possui uma propriedade chamada `undefined`). `x in window` é mais ou menos como testar se `window[x]` existe. Por isso - embora esteja dando o valor correto por "coincidência" - é uma forma incorreta, pois se está testando outra coisa.

Comment: O @mgibsonbr tem razão. E veja esse seu exemplo: `(function test() { var x; console.log(x in window); })();`. Isso não cria uma variável global (ou seja, propriedade de `window`; cria uma local. O que você está testando é se existe uma propriedade chamada "undefined" (que é o valor de x) em window, por isso dá true.

Comment: Essa postagem sempre me serve como referência. Na verdade, a resposta abaixo também. Rs

Answer (score 13):

As duas verificações que você mencionou servem para coisas diferentes.

#### 1. Variáveis não declaradas

Se uma variável não foi declarada, com `var variável = ...`, você não pode usá-la em comparações de igualdade como `if(variavel === undefined)`. Isso [lança um erro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/19273/como-verificar-se-uma-vari%C3%A1vel-est%C3%A1-definida?rq=1) porque a variável não existe.

Porém, o operador `typeof` aceita um operando que não exista. Por isso, pode-se usar `typeof variavel == "undefined"` para essa verificação. E esse teste com `typeof` também servem para verificar o segundo caso:

#### 2. Variáveis cujo valor é `undefined`

Uma variável existente pode conter o valor `undefined`. Nesse caso, é equivalente verificar com `variavel === undefined` ou `typeof variavel == "undefined"` – exceto no caso de a variável global `undefined` ter sido sobrescrita como o Vinícius citou na resposta dele, mas isso não é mais permitido pelos browsers modernos.

Answer (score 9):

Depende do que você quer testar:

### Se existe ou não uma variável com esse nome

Nesse caso, eu tentaria fazer uma operação com ela e observaria um `ReferenceError`:

```js
var x;

try {
  x + 1;
  document.body.innerHTML += "<pre>x existe</pre>";
} catch(e) {
  if ( e instanceof ReferenceError )
    document.body.innerHTML += "<pre>x não existe</pre>";
  else
    throw e;
}

try {
  y + 1;
  document.body.innerHTML += "<pre>y existe</pre>";
} catch(e) {
  if ( e instanceof ReferenceError )
    document.body.innerHTML += "<pre>y não existe</pre>";
  else
    throw e;
}
```

#### Se existe ou não uma variável *global* com esse nome

Nesse caso (e somente nesse caso) pode-se testar por sua presença no objeto global (nos *browsers*, `window`), como apontado na [resposta do Vinícius](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/78235/215):

```js
var a;

document.body.innerHTML += "<pre>a " + ("a" in window ? "" : "não ") + "existe.</pre>";
document.body.innerHTML += "<pre>b " + ("b" in window ? "" : "não ") + "existe.</pre>";

// Não funciona com variáveis locais a uma função
(function() {
  var c;

  document.body.innerHTML += "<pre style='color:red'>c " + ("c" in window ? "" : "não ") + "existe.</pre>";
  document.body.innerHTML += "<pre>d " + ("d" in window ? "" : "não ") + "existe.</pre>";
})();
```

### Se uma variável (existente ou não) é `undefined`

Como [apontado por bfavaretto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/78239/215), uma variável pode ser existente, válida, até já ter tido valor em algum momento, mas num determinado ponto ela pode ter recebido o valor `undefined`. Em muitos casos essa situação é indistinguível do caso em que a variável simplesmente não existe. Mas se você só quer saber se ela é *diferente de* `undefined` - i.e. se ela é definida - você pode usar o `typeof`:

```js
var a = 10;
var b;

document.body.innerHTML += "<pre>a" + (typeof(a) == "undefined" ? " não" : "") + " está definida.<pre>";
document.body.innerHTML += "<pre>b" + (typeof(b) == "undefined" ? " não" : "") + " está definida.<pre>";
document.body.innerHTML += "<pre>c" + (typeof(c) == "undefined" ? " não" : "") + " está definida.<pre>";
```

### Ok, e em que situação eu posso comparar diretamente com `undefined`?

Comparar com `undefined` (ou com [`void(0)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void)) provocará uma resposta diferente em cada um dos três casos acima: lançará uma exceção se a variável não existe, retornará `true` se ela existe mas possui o valor `undefined`, ou retornará `false` se ela existe mas possui outro valor. Note que a comparação sempre deve ser feita com `===` ou `!==`, nunca `==` ou `!=` (já que estas últimas são por demais imprevisíveis para se usar com segurança).

```js
"use strict";

var a = 10;
var b;

try {
  document.body.innerHTML += "<pre>a" + (a === undefined ? " não" : "") + " está definida.</pre>";
  document.body.innerHTML += "<pre>b" + (b === undefined ? " não" : "") + " está definida.</pre>";
  document.body.innerHTML += "<pre>c" + (c === undefined ? " não" : "") + " está definida.</pre>";
} catch(e) {
  document.body.innerHTML += "<pre>Erro: tentativa de acessar uma variável inexistente.</pre>";
}
```

Pessoalmente, eu considero ok essa forma, pois em geral acessar uma variável que não foi definida é um erro de programação, não algo que você vá querer testar em execução (exceto para fins de depuração, é claro). Usar simplesmente `variavel === undefined` e deixar a exceção propagar, caso `variavel` não exista, me parece uma forma adequada de programar.

Você pode ter um `try..catch` "genérico" só pro programa não "explodir" caso um erro desses passe despercebido, mas na minha opinião é inútil tentar tratar essa exceção. Pois como essa situação é inesperada (se fosse esperada, você simplesmente a corrigiria e declararia a variável!), dificilmente seu programa poderá [se recuperar desse erro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30124/215).