# Qual é a maneira segura para definir um valor padrão para um parâmetro de uma função?

Tags: javascript, parâmetros

Em PHP, posso fazer com que uma função tenha por padrão um valor em um parâmetro.

Exemplo:

```
function func($a = 1, $b = 2) {
   return $a + $b;
}
```

E no JavaScript? Consigo fazer a mesma declaração no `Firefox 39`;

```
function b (a=1) {
   return a;
}
```

Porém a recomendação que sempre vejo é:

```
function b (a) {
   a = a || 1;
   return a;
}
```

- Por que não usam a definição padrão de uma parâmetro, como se faz no PHP, já que é possível fazer isso?
- Existe alguma restrição quanto a versão do navegador que se usa?

**Observação**: Quando disse *qual é a maneira segura*, me refiro à segurança de que algo vá funcionar em qualquer navegador, independente da versão.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Passei por algo parecido e me disseram que era mais certo usar o exemplo como no [Link](http://www.linhadecomando.com/javascript/javascript-definindo-valores-padrao-para-os-parametros-faltantes-em-uma-funcao)

```
<script>
  function soma(a, b){
    if(typeof b == 'undefined') {
     b = 2;
    }
    document.write(a + b);
  }
  soma(2);
</script>
```

Assim como ele cita no post, me disseram a mesma coisa, "se fizer igual no PHP só o Firefox vai funcionar".

Eu testei e realmente se aplicava somente no Firefox, então pra mim, esse é o método mais seguro...

Comment: +1 Interessante. Como os caras geniais vão fazer algo que só funcione em `Firefox`!?!?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters também gostaria de saber rsrsrs...

Answer (score 7):

#### Hoje (2015) isto ainda não é possivel como no PHP. Mas no futuro, com ES6 é!

## O que é possível hoje (2015):

Hoje em dia, com a versão do JavaScript que os browsers usam isso não é possivel. A solução a usar é verificar o valor dentro da função, como referiste na pergunta.

Por exemplo:

```
function b(a){
   if (typeof a == 'undefined') a = 1;
   return a;
}
```

Nota: O Firefox já está a implementar algumas das ideias de ES6 mas isso nõ é compatível cross-browser hoje em dia, daí inviàvel em produção.

## Com ES6 - [*"Default function parameters"*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters)

Quando a nova versão de JavaScript fôr implementada nos browsers, como o Firefox já está a fazer neste caso, a solução será (segundo o que as especificações da [ECMAscript](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function-definitions)) como é no PHP (e que o Firefox já está a aplicar).

```
function b (a = 1) {
   return a;
}
console.log(b()); // dá: 1
```

Comment: É importante evirar a utilização de expressões lógicas diretamente no argumento, como `a = a || 1` ou `!a` pois há conversões automáticas de tipagem que podem provocar resultados falsos. Sugiro sempre comprar com `undefined`, incluindo a tipagem, utilizando o operador `===`.

Comment: @MFedatto tens razão. Para poupar confusões a quem não saiba isso editei a resposta.

Answer (score 6):

Realmente o valor *default* foi [introduzido recentemente e poucos navegadores o suportam](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/default_parameters) (alguns anos depois isso já é menos importante e tem soluções de [polyfill](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/194857/101) que se forem bem implementadas pode resolver os demais casos).

O ideal é fazer dentro da função. Você deve verificar se o valor é indefinido e aí estabelecer um valor para o parâmetro:

```
if (typeof(a) === 'undefined') a = 10;
if (typeof(b) === 'undefined') b = 20;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Typing/Default.js).

Tem uma [resposta mais completa sobre este padrão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/78208/101).

Answer (score 2):

É comum quando sabemos programar em uma determinada linguagem e estamos aprendendo outra, querer implementar funcionalidades da que já conhecemos, contudo isto não é o certo, devemos aprender a nova linguagem, e suas particularidades.

Por exemplo quero usar `explode` do `PHP` no `javascript`, posso pesquisar `explode em javascript`, mas meu resultado sera `.split`.

Devemos levar um consideração apenas os aspectos da linguagem que estamos lidando.

Fazendo uma analogia, podemos por do seguinte modo :
Tanto PHP como Javascript tem versões, contudo o PHP quem manda é você assim se você decidir trabalhar com 5.4 em seu servidos, este sera 5.4 para todos seus cliente. Ja o javascript seria "uma versao" não controlada, na qual quem define é o cliente escolhendo qual navegador ele quer usar.

Assim se você quer montar um código estável para todos, tera que implementar de modo que comporte todas as versões disponíveis.

Answer (score 1):

Não tenho bem a certeza se a declaração que funciona no Firefox 39 funciona em todos os navegadores. Porem a 2ª implementação deve funcionar sem problemas.
Visto que se chamar-mos a função sem parametros "b()" a variavel 'a' não vai ter valor ou seja 'undefined'. Essa condição "a || 1 " verifica se 'a' tem um valor associado caso não tenha torna-se o valor padrão "1". Caso a variavel já tenha um valor associado antes disso, vai apenas manter o seu valor

Comment: A atribuição `a = a || 1;` vai atribuir `1` ao chamar `b(0);` pois a expressão lógica direta vai converter o `0` para `false`.

Answer (score 1):

Os parâmetros predefinidos de uma função permitem que parâmetros regulares sejam inicializados com com valores iniciais caso undefined ou nenhum valor seja passado.

Síntaxe

```
function [nome]([param1[ = valorPredefinido1 ][, ..., paramN[ = valorPredefinidoN ]]]) {
   instruções
}
```

Com parâmetros padrão, a verificação no corpo da função não é mais necessário. Agora, você pode simplesmente colocar um como o valor padrão para b na cabeça função:

```
function multiply(a, b = 1) {
  return a*b;
}

multiply(5); // 5
```

A compatibilidade para utilização desta funcionalidade, seriam as seguintes:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E para o mobile:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

fonte: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Parametros_Predefinidos

Comment: esta notação é definida pelo ES6, nem de perto é compatível com todos os Browsers.

Comment: legal amigo, os parametros default conforme foi perguntado, só funcionam no firefox, conforme demonstrei e comprovei com a imagem da tabela acima, então porque o negativo ? desnecessário, ignorância da parte de quem fez isso, leia a fonte pra informa-se melhor