# O que é um shim?

Tags: javascript, aplicação-web, terminologia

Ao perguntar sobre ["o que é um Polyfill?"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/194857), esbarrei entre comentários e pesquisas com o termo *Shim*.

- O que seria um *Shim*?
- Qual é a relação do termo *Shim* com o termo *polyfill*?
- *Shim* está diretamente ligado ao Javascript, assim como o *Polyfill*?

Answer (score 4):

Buscando contribuir proativamente, e também respeitando as respostas em inglês: [[What is a Shim? - En, 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2116157/3542189)]. Pretendo responder de forma simples e objetiva. Então, temos o seguinte conceito de Shim:

> O Shim Infrastructure implementa uma forma de **hooking** de interface de programação de aplicativos (API). Especificamente, aproveita a natureza da ligação para redirecionar as chamadas de API do próprio Windows para o código alternativo - o próprio shim. [[Technet Microsoft, 2011](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd837644(v=WS.10).aspx)]

---

De início, entendemos de que se trata apenas de mais um conceito, mas considerando:

> A infra-estrutura de compatibilidade de aplicativos do Microsoft Windows (Shim Infrastructure) **é uma dessas soluções técnicas poderosas** [veja bem: **é uma dessas soluções técnicas poderosas**]. À medida que o sistema operacional Windows evolui de versão para mudança de versão para suportar nova tecnologia, incorporar correções de bugs e implementar uma modificação na estratégia - as mudanças na implementação de algumas funções podem afetar aplicativos que dependem deles. [[Technet Microsoft, 2011](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd837644(v=WS.10).aspx)]

Se considerarmos a idéia de ganchos (***hooking***) para modificar o comportamento de API's e assim melhorarmos, com novas tecnologias, ou corrigir bugs se de **soluções técnicas poderosas** ao implementarem as features de regressão para aplicações antigos (ou no caso de Polyfill: navegadores antigos [[Stack Overflow - a, 2017](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/194867/6789)]). Para ilustrar veja a seguinte figura:

[image: Shim]

Claro que o uso do Shim Infrastructure se justifica:

> Para reduzir os custos de implantação e acelerar a adoção, [...] para garantir ampla compatibilidade de software existente, conduzindo a compatibilidade ao processo de engenharia e liberação. [[Technet Microsoft, 2011](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd837644(v=WS.10).aspx)]

Com a explicação acima, espero ter respondido: ***O que seria um Shim?***.

---

Agora, ***Qual é a relação do termo Shim com o termo polyfill?*** Podemos considerar novamente a citação, o polyfill é:

> Um shim que imita uma API futura fornecendo funcionalidade de retorno para navegadores mais antigos. [[Paul Irish](https://www.paulirish.com/i/7570.png)]

Então, a relação Shim Vs polyfill, é que polyfill - *é um Shim no contexto (se, somente se) em que a aplicação seja um navegador antido sendo melhorado*.
No caso em que a aplicação seja um navegador, então usamos o jargão técnico polyfill.

---

E para finalizar: ***Shim está diretamente ligado ao Javascript, assim como o Polyfill?***

Podemos categorizar que Shim está em um escopo maior, isto é, para qualquer aplicação que estamos implementando ganchos de API's, mesmo para um navegador, estamos praticando soluções técnicas Shim. Então, podemos afirmar que Shim ***não está diretamente ligado ao Javascript***, assim como, nem o Polyfill esteja ligado ao javascript diretamente porque temos outras linguagens que implemente funcionalidades relacionadas ao navegador.

---

**Referência**: 
<sub>[What is a Shim? - En, 2010], Disponível em: **[Site Stack Overflow em inglês](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd837644(v=WS.10).aspx)**. Acesso: 8 Abr, 2017</sub> 
<sub>[Technet Microsoft, 2011], Disponível em: **[Site Technet Microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd837644(v=WS.10).aspx)**. Acesso: 8 Abr, 2017</sub> 
<sub>[Stack Overflow - a, 2017], Disponível em: **[Stack Overflow: O que é Polyfill?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/194867/6789)**. Acesso: 8 Abr, 2017</sub> 
<sub>[Paul Irish]. Disponível em **[site pessoal](https://www.paulirish.com/i/7570.png)**. Acesso: 8 Abr, 2017.</sub>