# Quando e por que usar o :hover e onMouserOver e onMouseOut?

Tags: javascript, css

Estou estudando sobre *:hover*, *onMouseOver* e *onMouseOut*. Suponhamos que nesta situação eu queira alterar o fundo de uma imagem quando passar o *mouse* em cima dela.

Qual é a forma correta de programar? É usando CSS (*:hover*) ou através de JavaScript (*onMouseOver* e *onMouseOut*)? Porque?

```html
<div id="img1">
    <img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/unmario/images/a/ad/300px-Nsmb-mushroom-super.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20081217191119">
</div>

<div id="img2">
    <img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/unmario/images/a/ad/300px-Nsmb-mushroom-super.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20081217191119">
</div>
```

Comment: CSS sempre que possivel. Uma pergunta: essa aplicação será usada em tablets ou telefones?

Comment: Sim, o usuário poderá acessar através do telefone ! Sendo assim é bom evitar javascript certo?

Comment: Sendo assim é bom evitar essa funcionalidade :) Descreve como farias se `:hover` ou `mouseover` não existisse.

Comment: Vish, faria algo como deixar duas imagens sobrepostas e uma fica invisível ou algo do tipo kkkk (se não existisse o `mouseover`ou `:hover`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso vai depender do efeito que você quer fazer, se você quiser que simplesmente ele altere a imagem e nada mais, utilize o hover no css, assim a aplicação ficará mais leve, se você quiser um hover personalizado, que o fade demore mais ou algo do tipo, utilize o css também, é o mesmo caso, a aplicação ficará mais leve.

Mas se você esta pensando em compatibilidade com navegadores antigos, utilize então um script javascript.

Comment: Entendi @Wictor, obrigado pela explicação !!

Comment: O hover pode alterar a imagem dentro de uma div?

Comment: (7 minutos para aceitar a resposta)

Comment: Alterar o src da imagem não, mas você pode colocar esta imagem como background assim você consegue alterar utilizando css.

Comment: Certo, vou tentar por hover aqui e dar uma estudada, valeu !!

Answer (score 3):

CSS deve ser utilizado para tratar o *layout* e JavaScript a parte lógica.

Sempre que possível opte por utilizar CSS. Faça o uso de JavaScript em casos no qual as *features* do CSS não conseguem suprir suas necessidades e talvez precise agregar funcionalidade ([*polyfills*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/194857/4808)) - você pode utilizar o [*Can I use*](https://caniuse.com/) para checar o *status* das funcionalidades nos navegadores.

Considere também que existem usuários que desabilitam o JavaScript por completo no navegador, há quem utilize extensões que permitem JS somente em páginas específicas. Utilizar somente CSS é uma garantia que você tem de que sua página será exibida da mesma forma para todos os usuários.

Comment: Pow, entendi perfeitamente !! Obrigado pela resposta @Renan !! foi de grande ajuda