# Como fazer com que ao apertar o botão enviar não precise rolar a pagina para ver a mensagem que role sozinho ao clicar no botão

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```
  <div class="botao">
                <button id="enviar" type="button" value="ENVIAR">Enviar</button>
                <button id="refazer" value="REFAZER" type="submit" disabled="disabled">Fazer Novamente</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <br>

        <div id="resultado">

        </div>

        <script>
            $("#refazer").click(function() {
                document.querySelector('#formulario').reset();
            });

            $("#enviar").click(function() {
                if (document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]:checked').length < 20) {
                    alert("Você ainda não respondeu todas as perguntas.");
                } else {

                    var total = 0;

                    $("input[type=radio]:checked").each(function() {
                        total += parseFloat($(this).val());

                        function checkInputs(inputs) {

                   var filled = true;

                 inputs.forEach(function(input) {

                if(input.value === 20) {
                filled = false;
              }

             });

            return filled;

             }

           var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
           var button = document.querySelector("button");

          inputs.forEach(function(input) {

         input.addEventListener("keyup", function() {

          if(checkInputs(inputs)) {
          button.disabled = false;
         } else {
         button.disabled = true;
         }

        });

      });
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 1):

O método [`Element.scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) rola o ancestral do elemento, caixa de rolagem, de forma que, o elemento no qual o método `scrollIntoView()` é chamado, fique visível para o usuário.

O método possui três sobrecargas:

```
scrollIntoView()
scrollIntoView(alignToTop)
scrollIntoView(scrollIntoViewOptions)
```

Onde os parâmetros:

- `alignToTop` é um valor booleano:

  - Se `true`, a parte superior do elemento será alinhada à parte superior da área visível da caixa de rolagem.
  - Se `false`, a parte inferior do elemento será alinhada à parte inferior da área visível da caixa de rolagem.
- `scrollIntoViewOptions` objeto com as seguintes propriedades:

  - `behavior`: Define a animação de transição, os valores são:

    - `auto`: Este valor permite o salto abrupto entre elementos dentro da caixa de rolagem. É o valor na falta.
    - `smooth`. faz a transição suave dentro da caixa de rolagem.
  - `block`: Define o alinhamento vertical do elemento após a transição, os valores são:

    - `start`: o elemento é alinhado na parte superior da caixa de rolagem, é o valor na falta.
    - `center`: o elemento é alinhado no meio da caixa de rolagem.
    - `end`: o elemento é alinhado na parte inferior da caixa de rolagem.
    - `nearest`: Caso o elemento esteja visível permanece na mesma posição caso o elemento não esteja visível ele será alinhado verticalmente a extremidade mais próxima da caixa de rolagem.
  - `inline`: Define o alinhamento horizontal.

    - `start`: o elemento é alinhado à esquerda da caixa de rolagem.
    - `center`: o elemento é alinhado ao centro esquerda da caixa de rolagem.
    - `end`: o elemento é alinhado à direita da caixa de rolagem.
    - `nearest`: Caso o elemento esteja visível permanece na mesma posição caso o elemento não esteja visível ele será alinhado horizontalmente a lateral mais próxima da caixa de rolagem, é o valor na falta.

> **Nota:**
> Antes de usar o método `scrollIntoView()` em produção verifique a [tabela de
> compatibilidade](https://caniuse.com/scrollintoview) com os navegadores pois em maioria o é suportado,
> mas em alguns browsers a opção `smooth`, para conferir suavização a
> rolagem, não é suportada. Se a suavização de rolagem é mandatória será necessário o uso de um [polyfill](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/194857/o-que-%C3%A9-polyfill).

```js
//Para uma melhor experiência de visualização rode o exemplo aqui 
//no Stack Snippets como Página Toda ou Expandir trecho de código.

let btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
let btn2 = document.getElementById("btn2");
let btn3 = document.getElementById("btn3");
let div1 = document.getElementById("div1");
let div2 = document.getElementById("div2");
let div3 = document.getElementById("div3");

btn1.addEventListener("click", function() {
  div2.scrollIntoView({
    behavior: "smooth",
    block: "start"
  });
});

btn2.addEventListener("click", function() {
  div3.scrollIntoView({
    behavior: "smooth",
    block: "start"
  });
});

btn3.addEventListener("click", function() {
  div1.scrollIntoView({
    behavior: "auto",
    block: "start"
  });
});
```

```css
#div2 {
  position: relative;
  top: 800px;
}

#div3 {
  position: relative;
  top: 1500px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <p>Primeiro parágrafo</p>
  <button id="btn1" type="button">Ir para o segundo parágrafo</button>
</div>
<div id="div2">
  <p>Segundo parágrafo</p>
  <button id="btn2" type="button">Ir para o terceiro parágrafo</button>
</div>
<div id="div3">
  <p>Terceiro parágrafo</p>
  <button id="btn3" type="button">Retornar o primeiro parágrafo</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Você deveria receber um prêmio. Deu uma resposta completa e elaborada para uma questão duvidosa de um usuário com UM ponto de reputação, que escreve o próprio nome em maiúsculas e nunca mais voltou aqui nem para agradecer. Parabéns. Pena que não existe badge para isso.

Answer (score -2):

Você pode adicionar um id na div que mostra a msg, e no redirecionamento adicionar # e o id da div, exemplo:

```
header('Location: /pagina#div');
```

Dessa forma o próprio navegador irá rolar até a div com o id. E caso queira adicionar efeitos nessa rolagem, precisaria usar javascript.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).