# javascript verificar se o atributo de um objeto existe

Tags: javascript

Tenho um objeto que recebo, e as vezes ele vem com um atributo outras vezes não, meu problema é na sequencia quando vou trabalhar com ele veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
if( json.aviso != ""  ){ 
                    //...fazer alguma coisa 
                }
```

Só que quando o objeto não vem com o atributo *json.aviso* ele executa o que esta dentro do *if*, creio eu porque *null* é diferente de "" teria uma forma mais elegante de tratar isso do fazer como:

```
if( json.aviso != "" && json.aviso !=null ){  //...me parece gambiarra }
```

Comment: Você pode fazer dessa forma: 
`if ((json.hasOwnProperty("aviso")) && (json.aviso  !== ""))`

Answer (score 7):

Existem 3 situações que você precisa prestar atenção:

1. O atributo não existe ou seu valor é `undefined`;
2. O atributo existe e seu valor é `null`;
3. O atributo existe e seu valor é *"falsy"* (`false`, `0`, `""`, etc).

A maneira mais garantida de diferenciar entre os casos é usando os operadores `===` e `!==`, pois eles levam o tipo dos operandos em consideração além dos seus valores, enquanto `==` e `!=` têm regras de comparação que nem sempre são intuitivas.

Alguns exemplos:

```js
var obj = { a:"foo", b:"", c:42, d:0, e:true, f:false, g:null, h:undefined };

[].forEach.call("abcdefghi", function(prop) {
    document.body.innerHTML += "<p>Testando: " + prop + " (" + obj[prop] + ")</p>";

    testa(prop, " === undefined");
    testa(prop, " === null");
    testa(prop, " === false");
    testa(prop, ' === ""');
    testa(prop, ' === 0');

    testa(prop, " == undefined");
    testa(prop, " == null");
    testa(prop, " == false");
    testa(prop, ' == ""');
    testa(prop, ' == 0');
});

function testa(prop, expr) {
    if ( eval("obj['" + prop + "'] " + expr) )
        document.body.innerHTML += "<p>obj." + prop + " " + expr + "</p>";
}
```

Minha sugestão é listar os casos em que sua condição se aplica e combiná-los com `&&`, tal como você está fazendo. Se é gambiarra ou não, não sei dizer, mas se for, é uma questão de necessidade imposta pela linguagem...

---

P.S. Você pode estar se perguntando: "mas como diferenciar entre o caso em que um atributo não existe de fato e o caso em que ele existe mas seu valor é `undefined`?". Bom, eu estou me perguntando a mesma coisa, mas não me recordo de existir um meio pra isso.

No caso de variáveis até que dá (ver a pergunta ["Como verificar undefined de maneira correta no Javascript"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/78208/215) pra mais detalhes), mas no caso de propriedades de objetos, receio que não (até mesmo converter o objeto para JSON fará com que as propriedades existentes mas com valor `undefined` desapareçam do resultado - pois JSON não suporta `undefined`).

Answer (score 3):

Você pode fazer dessa forma:

`if ((json.hasOwnProperty("aviso")) && (!!json.aviso))`

Dessa forma primeiro irá verificar se o objeto cujo nome é json existe a propriedade `aviso` e por último irá verificar o valor dele, dessa forma você garante que está sendo verificada a existência da propriedade e o valor dela.

Edit:

Existe uma maneira mais eficaz ainda que é apenas deixar o `!!json.aviso`

`if (!!json.aviso)`

Answer (score 1):

Também uso esta função `Objeto.hasOwnProperty("nome elemento")`, ai só jogar em uma condição por exemplo:

```
if(Objeto.hasOwnProperty("nome elemento")){
   return "ação desejada"

}else{
"uma outra ação de sua escolha"
}
```

geralmente é sempre eficaz, uso no caso de conversões de `xml` para `json` em `xml` divergentes

Answer (score 0):

```
if(json.aviso) {
   //code
}
```

porém, se o valor do seu aviso é igual a `""`, não vai cair no seu if

Também vale ressaltar que:
Essa solução só é 100% válida em casos que o valor contido dentro de aviso não é numérico, pois quando o valor é numérico e ele possui o valor 0 o código dentro da cláusula if não é executado

Comment: Essa solução só é 100% válida em casos que o valor contido dentro de `aviso` não é numérico, pois quando o valor é numérico e ele possui o valor 0 o código dentro da cláusula if não é executado

Comment: humm, realmente..
bem interessante.