# Comparação em Javascript esta pulando direto

Tags: javascript

Estou fazendo uma pagina de cadastro com **5** dropdowns em cada linha, porém o usuário não será obrigado a preencher todos os dropdowns para concluir o cadastro, por exemplo, caso o usuário preencha toda a primeira linha de cadastro, automaticamente a segunda linha ficará disponível para que se ele quiser ele possa preencher também, porém caso ele não a preencha ele poderá mandar apenas para o banco o conteúdo da primeira linha, como posso verificar se a segunda linha também foi preenchida em *javascript*?

Tentei dessa forma:

```
if ($data.formInput.codEmpresaOTRS01.codigoEmpresa.length > 1 && $data.formInput.codEmpresaOTRS02.codigoEmpresa.length > 1){
    //Quando tanto a segunda linha quanto a primeira for preenchida
    x = 2;
} else if ($data.formInput.codEmpresaOTRS01.codigoEmpresa.length > 1){
   //Quando a primeira for preenchida apenas
   x = 1;
}
return x;
```

Mas ele não entra na segunda condição, o que poderá estar errado nessas comparações?

Comment: Não ficou muito claro a forma como você está organizou seu html, poderia postar o código do formulário na pergunta? Outra coisa, são somente 2 linhas de cadastro no máximo?

Comment: Não são duas linhas apenas mas acredito que quando eu conseguir fazer funcionar para duas linha basta replicar para as outras linhas. E o código HTML eu não tenho acesso pois utilizo uma ferramenta onde eu arrasto os itens para a tela e ela mesmo gera o designer da pagina, eu consigo apenas colocar codigos (javascript, json, etc) para rodar por tras, meu problema pelo que notei é que essa variavel `$data.formInput.codEmpresaOTRS01.codigoEmpresa` vem em branco, mas não é nula no caso, simplesmente não contém nada

Comment: Ah um modo de verificar se a variável esta em branco no javascript @PedroSouza

Comment: Porque se eu coloco `return $$data.formInput.codEmpresaOTRS01.codigoEmpresa` e chamo isso na minha tela de desenvolvimento, enquanto eu não seleciono nada no dropdown que eu atribui essa variável não me é exibido nada

Comment: Se essa variável for global, e você tiver acesso ao console de desenvolvedor (no Google Chrome tem por exemplo), pode usar diretamente o `console.log($data.formInput.codEmpresaOTRS01.codigoEmpresa)` e ver o que retorna. Pode usar também esse comando no seu código e ver em tempo de execução o que é impresso no console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri o que precisava a partir dessa [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/19273/como-verificar-se-uma-vari%C3%A1vel-est%C3%A1-definida), não é que minha variável estava em branco ou nula e sim é que ela não tinha sido definida ainda